# Rendering dynamic models

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to render a model which is loaded dynamically (e.g. via ajax call) and its properties are identified based on its type.

I have several templates each suitable for rendering a particular type of object, and instantiate specific template based on the object type, using `if` parameter of `template` binding. As said in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html):

> This can be useful for preventing a null observable from being bound against a template before it is populated.

On the first load, the model is successfully rendered. When I try to render a different object, i got `Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: property is not defined;` error.

What is the best practice for rendering in case when part of the model is volatile?

Here is sample view:

```
<button data-bind="click: loadFruit">Show fruit</button>
<button data-bind="click: loadAnimal">Show animal</button>
<h2>Now showing: <span data-bind="text: objType"></span></h2>
<div data-bind="with: obj">
  <dl data-bind="template: { name: 'fruitTemplate', if: $parent.objType() == 'fruit' }"></dl>
  <dl data-bind="template: { name: 'animalTemplate', if: $parent.objType() == 'animal' }"></dl>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="fruitTemplate">
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd data-bind="text: name"></dd>
  <dt>Color</dt>
  <dd data-bind="text: color"></dd>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="animalTemplate">
  <dt>How may legs?</dt>
  <dd data-bind="text: numLegs"></dd>
  <dt>Has Tail?</dt>
  <dd data-bind="text: hasTail"></dd>
</script>
```

and viewmodel:

```
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.objType = ko.observable('n/a');
  this.obj = ko.observable();
  this.loadFruit = function() {
    self.obj ({name:'apple', color: 'green'});
    self.objType ('fruit');
  }
  this.loadAnimal = function() {
    self.obj ({numLegs:4, hasTail: true});
    self.objType ('animal');
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

You can try it with [associated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmcKN/7/).

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not the best practice solution, but very easy to implement: http://jsfiddle.net/hmcKN/9/

Just set `objType` to a non-existing template before changing the other values. Then set all required observables and finally specify the correct template.